# Query Regarding Relation in ERD using DBDesigner

Tags: mysql, erd

How can we represent a relation where there is no need to add a foreign key in the table in DBDesigner? For Example, If i have 2 Tables As:

1) Admin
2) Machine

Suppose the relation "Admin can Add machines",

there is no need of Admin table's primary key to go in Machine's table as foreign key. Or you can say that i don't want to add it. But still i want to show this relation in my ERD. How can i do it using DBDesigner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create separate table `Permissions`.
Then there will be a row with specific permission **Add machines**
This way you can assign different permissions to different users.

Obviously you will need 2 more tables for this to work: `Users` where the user data is kept and say `user_permissions` with 2 fields only `user_id & permission_id` where you keep the info which user has which permission.

This is the right way to design scalable permissions that can expand and accommodate any set of permissions.